# Procfile error during capistrano deploy of Spree Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, spree, procfile

I solved many problems already, but struggling with this one.

Deploy environment:
ubuntu 12.10
rvm 1.18.21 (stable)
ruby 1.9.3p392

Getting this error with

```
cap deploy:cold
```

Error:

```
  * 2013-03-23 18:01:27 executing `deploy:start'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:start'
  * 2013-03-23 18:01:27 executing `foreman:export'
  * executing "cd /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/current && bundle exec foreman export bluepill /data/picurwebaruhaz/shared/config"
    servers: ["198.211.117.84"]
    [198.211.117.84] executing command
 ** [out :: 198.211.117.84] ERROR: Procfile does not exist.
 ** [out :: 198.211.117.84] 
    command finished in 1430ms
```

My deploy.rb:
https://gist.github.com/gwuix2/5228473

Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/gwuix2/5228488

Comment: Is there actually a `Procfile` in the root of your app?  Check and make sure it is also checked in to your SCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spree's docs, it looks like you need to generate a `Procfile` (which is used by [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html)) in your app before deploying it.

> [Spree guide to Application Processes](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/deployment_application_processes.html)

That guide shows a default `Procfile`'s contents, which you may be able to get by with. Spree also has a [deployment service](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/deployment_service.html) which can take care of generating several things for you, including the `Procfile`:

> Every server will get some basic configuration, such as Rails Environment environment variable, placeholder directories for your Spree application, automatically generated database.yml and Procfile files, and more.

So that may be worth looking into, because even if you are able to generate the `Procfile` manually, you may run into more issues from missing config files, and their deployment service may take care of all of that for you automatically.